# Is it possible to enable or disable VoiceOver within an iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, jailbreak, voiceover

I would like to be able to turn VoiceOver on or off within my iOS app.  The reason for this is I am trying to help a person with disabilities which render her unable to read messages (hence the need for VoiceOver), and who is also unable to triple click the home-button due to motor coordination problems. The way to the setting through Settings>General>Accessibility>VoiceOver>VoiceOver>Flipswitch is far too long and complicated.

Is it possible, without jailbreaking the device, to change this setting in an app?  The app doesn't need to make it to the App Store, if that helps.

Alternatively, is it easy to do this with a jailbroken device?

Another approach may be to simulate the triple-click on the home-button that automatically turns on VoiceOver. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the new [Assistive Touch](http://pogue.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/11/10/apples-assistivetouch-helps-the-disabled-use-a-smartphone/?src=me&ref=technology) feature?

Comment: Yes, I have, it will also be used.
I am unable to figure out a way to get it to triple click the homebutton or otherwise turn on the voiceover feature though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the app [aHomeIcon](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ahomeicon/id417171558?mt=8&uo=4).
2. Open the app and tap URL.
3. Insert the url: prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
4. Tap 'Done'.
5. Insert a name to be shown below the icon.
6. Tap the export button at the bottom of the page. Safari opens.
7. Add a bookmark and select 'to home-screen'.

Now you can tap that icon and you are redirected to the accessibility part of the settings app.

See this [link](http://www.mokten.com/2011/11/ios-5-custom-url-for-settings-app/) for reference.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. I am almost there.
I am able to get to the accessibility-page, but not further into the voiceover setting. Ideally I want to flip the switch automatically, but that might not be possible, is it atleast possible to get into the voiceover-screen?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.